# Unable to install office365 package in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install Office365 package using the following command

```
pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client
```

But I am getting the following error

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001931FEF6CD0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/office365-rest-python-client/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001931FEF6D90>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/office365-rest-python-client/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001931FEFF5E0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/office365-rest-python-client/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001931FEFF040>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/office365-rest-python-client/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001931FEFF8B0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/office365-rest-python-client/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Office365-REST-Python-Client (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Office365-REST-Python-Client
```

I have checked my python version, it is 3.10.8 and as per [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/) this version is supported for this package. Can someone help me with the solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have python 3.10 and managed to install this package. seems you are behind a proxy and cannot contact pypi. you should specify the proxy in the pip command like below (if proxy's ip is let's say 10.10.10.10 and port 8080)

pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client --proxy "http://10.10.10.10:8080"